# How to disable running builds on commit for a gitrepo resource

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-pipelines

I have a git repo resource, but I don't want to trigger run on every commit into this repository. is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

We should disable buildOn Commit here. for example,

```
- name: my_app_repo
  type: GitRepo
  configuration:
    gitProvider: my_github
    path: myuser/repo-name
    branches:
      include: master
    buildOn:
      commit: false
```

[Reference](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GitRepo#GitRepo-Tags)